# Ampscript to find Publication List Name

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, ampscript

Hi I'm trying to get a list name back from a publication list using `AMPscript` and retrieveRequest. This is all being done within an ET landing page.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

```
 %%[    

SET @rr = CreateObject("RetrieveRequest")  

SetObjectProperty(@rr, "ObjectType", "List")  
AddObjectArrayItem(@rr,"Properties","ID")  
AddObjectArrayItem(@rr,"Properties","ListName")  


SET @sfp = CreateObject("SimpleFilterPart")  
SetObjectProperty(@sfp, "Property", "ID")  
SetObjectProperty(@sfp, "SimpleOperator", "equals")  
AddObjectArrayItem(@sfp, "Value", [list name value from link in GUI])    
SetObjectProperty(@rr, "Filter", @sfp) 

SET @sub = InvokeRetrieve(@rr)  

SET @ListName = Field(@sub,"ListName") 

 %%=v(@ListName)=%%

]%%
```

Comment: Are you passing the list `ID` or the the list `Name` in the filter? Do you get any results without the filter?

Comment: The %%=v(@ListName)=%% needs to be outside of your AMPScript %%[ ]%% block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also,

The RetrieveRequest gives back an array of objects. So you would need to loop thru it to reference that..Pseudo code below.

Number of Rows Returned: %%=RowCount(@sub)=%%

```
%%[   
For @i = 1 to RowCount(@Sub) do   
 Set @ListName = Field(Row(@Sub,@i),"ListName")   
]%%   
ListName %%=v(@ListName)=%%

%%[next @i]%%
```

Answer (score 0):

The ET documentation for AMPscript API calls, is dreadful, so your help is greatly appreciated.

Working code:

```
%%[    

SET @rr = CreateObject("RetrieveRequest")  

SetObjectProperty(@rr, "ObjectType", "List")  
AddObjectArrayItem(@rr,"Properties","ID")  
AddObjectArrayItem(@rr,"Properties","ListName")  


SET @sfp = CreateObject("SimpleFilterPart")  
SetObjectProperty(@sfp, "Property", "ID")  
SetObjectProperty(@sfp, "SimpleOperator", "equals")  
AddObjectArrayItem(@sfp, "Value", [ID number from hovering over GUI link])    
SetObjectProperty(@rr, "Filter", @sfp) 

SET @sub = InvokeRetrieve(@rr)  

]%%


%%[
For @i = 1 to RowCount(@Sub) do
Set @ListName = Field(Row(@Sub,@i),"ListName")
]%%

ListName %%=v(@ListName)=%%

%%[next @i]%%
```